# Precalculate the Normalization of a filter size

Tags: image-processing, filters, gabor, normalization

If we have an Image I and a Gabor filter created at specific size and orientation, assume that is `11x11`.

I saw some persons who normalize the size of the filter, but i didn't understand what was meant by "precalculate the normalization of the filter size". And within the normalization, they square the image, for example : `Isquare = I^2`. So why the image is squared ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each pixel of the filter has a magnitude (intensity). The square function equivalently calculate the power density of the pixel. The normalization is to scale the filter power to 1. That's where `I^2` at the denominator comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, ,,normalization'' means to make the L2 norm (sum of squares) of a signal $1$. This is usually achieved by calculating the inverse of the sum of squares and multiplying by it.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand well what do you mean. What was meant by "sum of squares" ? and why the image is squared ? please can you edit your response to include more explanation :) thank's in advance!